# b.sum() yields 0 while b.rolling(2).sum() yields nan, where b=pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`pandas.sum()` will skip NaN by default, so I would expect `b.rolling(2).sum()` to also replace the NaN with 0. However, `b.rolling(2).sum()` yields NaN instead of 0, where `b = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) method takes a `min_periods` parameter, which defaults to the size of the window. Until that many *non-missing* values are accumulated, the rolling calculation will leave the values missing. All your values are missing, so the calculation will never accumulate 2 values.

For this all-NaN case, you could just set the parameter to 0.

```py
pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN]).rolling(2, min_periods=0).sum()                                                                                                                                                                         
# 0    0.0
# 1    0.0
```

But this will also change the behavior for series where the first two values *are* present. It will leave the first value in place, not empty to indicate that there weren't 2 values in the rolling sum yet.

```py
pd.Series([1, 2]).rolling(2).sum()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# 0    NaN
# 1    3.0

pd.Series([1, 2]).rolling(2, min_periods=0).sum()                                                                                                                                                                                   
# 0    1.0
# 1    3.0
```

To avoid that, I would need to know more about your use case.